# How can I change the value of an element being constantly modified by setInterval() callback function on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I'm a beginner working on a pomodoro timer. Currently the button you press to start the timer changes over to the current time left once activated.

One of the features I want to include is that the user is able to hover the time left to hide it and display the word "Pause" instead, without interrupting the timer in the background.

[image: hover event demonstration]

From what I understand, I need to do this using JS (jquery .hover() maybe). My confusion with implementing this is that I only want this interaction to be possible while the timer is running, which is when it is being overwritten every second. And as I'm using setInterval() to call a function every second, I would need to (as far as I understand) define the hover functions inside the setInterval callback function. However this produces unexpected results and not at all what is intended.

Another way I thought of doing it is to display a hidden div that has absolute positioning over the timer, whenever the user hovers the timer. But I'm not sure how to implement this.

If someone can help me make this happen I'd be very grateful.

code pen: http://codepen.io/meek/pen/zradga

```
function activateTimer() {
    if(inProgress===false) {
      inProgress = true;
      updateTimer(sSession);
      interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(sSession>0) {
          // session time!
          focusSession();
          sSession -= 1;
          updateTimer(sSession);
        }
        else {
          // break time!
          if(sBreak>1) {
            focusBreak();
            sBreak -= 1;
            updateTimer(sBreak);
          }
          // this prevents a one second delay when break reaches 0 by not running the whole setInterval() callback function once without changing a value.
          else if (sBreak==1){
            // start a new session
            sBreak -= 1;
            updateTimer(sBreak);
            sSession = session*60;
            sBreak = breaks*60;
          }
        }
      }, 1000);

      // change hover effect
      $('#timer').removeClass('hovergreen');
      $('#timer').addClass('hoverred');
    }
    else {
      inProgress = false;
      clearInterval(interval);

      // change hover effect
      $('#timer').removeClass('hoverred');
      $('#timer').addClass('hovergreen');
    }
  }
```

This is the huge monster of a function that currently contains most of the functionality of the timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make simple change to your HTML (add a `div` with `pause` class):

```
<div class="meter">
   <div class="pause">Pause</div>
   <div class="meter-container"></div>
   <div class="base"></div>
   <div id="timer" class="timer btn hovergreen">START</div>
</div>
```

add then this CSS:

```
.meter{
    position: relative;
}
.meter .pause{
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.meter:hover .meter-container, .meter:hover .base, .meter:hover .timer{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.meter:hover .pause{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This causes the entire meter to disappear or move which is not the intended effect.

Comment: Do u need the meter to remain in place, and just the **START** change to **PAUSE**, and the meter stop it motion?

Comment: At the moment, the meter doesn't matter. I only need the timer (numbers) to switch to PAUSE on mouse over while they're counting down (and only while they're counting down). So I require a JS solution.

Comment: should the counter, still count down in the background, while the mouse is hovering the number?

Comment: exactly. I finally figured it out though, partly thanks to your answer. I've answered my own question if you want to check out how I did it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured out how to do it. I created an absolute position div with "pause" with display set to none.

I simply need to check if inProgress (my variable that is set to true if the timer is running and false if it is not) is true inside a hover callback function, for both the timer and the pause div (to avoid the awkward situation where the user hovers over the timer, the hidden pause div appears and suddenly they aren't hovering over the timer anymore, triggering the pause fade, etc).

So basically this:

```
  $('#timer').hover(function(){
    if(inProgress) {
      $('#pause').css('display', 'block');
    }
  },
                    function() {
    $('#pause').css('display', 'none');
  });

  $('#pause').hover(function() {
    $('#pause').css('display', 'block');
  },
                   function() {
    $('#pause').css('display', 'none');
  });
```

code pen: http://codepen.io/meek/pen/zradga